# Issue while using cassandra-driver for allow filtering

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

We face issues while using "allow filtering" through cassandra-driver. When I make the following statement in cqlsh, it works perfectly

```
select * from social_media.posts where query_id='286eb6b6-5fc4-59a6-8fff-40035101708d' and source='twitter' and relevant=true limit 10000 allow filtering;
```

But when I use the same query using the cassandra-driver execute function I run into the following error.

```
rows = session.execute("select * from social_media.posts where query_id='286eb6b6-5fc4-59a6-8fff-40035101708d' and source='twitter' and relevant=True allow filtering;")

[Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'QUORUM'}
```

However, it does work for "relevant=False" filter.

What could be causing this issue? And how can it be fixed?

For reference, we set the consistency to QUORUM when we initiate the connection to the db. We are using cassandra-driver (3.0.0). We also tried moving to the latest version. But this did not help us.

Comment: Perhaps, re-write your query/model so that it doesn't *need* ALLOW FILTERING?  It's amazing how so many problems with Cassandra *vanish* when tables are designed to suit a specific query, and don't require poor performing shortcuts to work.

Comment: This is cross-posted https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/topic/python-driver-user/sKDbAqiBxNY/discussion

Please, if you're going to post in SO, just provide a link in the ML.

Comment: @AdamHolmberg Sorry for not having posted the link. This issue was fixed by bringing up a new node if a node is down for more than gc_grace_seconds.